# External Storage Files Getting Deleted on Uninstalling the App

Tags: android, android-download-manager

My app uses the DownloadManager to download files, These are downloading properly but when I uninstall the app all files are getting deleted.

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/FolderName");
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(file_name)
            .setDescription("")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/FolderName", file_name);
```

When I uninstalled the app, my complete data was gone.

**Now i found that this is happening in Motorola devices only.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure? Because normally external storage will not get cleared AUTO on app un-installation. check WhatApp, Facebook as a example.

Comment: @GaneshAB-Android - Yes I am sure, this is happening in my app. As I uninstalled the app my complete data was deleted.

Comment: Is this behaviour for all other apps? Try with any other app..

Comment: @GaneshAB-Android : In Whatsapp and FB this doesn't happens. But this is happening in my case.